# Cant see the Google Maps Marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have added a Google Map to my project and 
I can see the map, but the inserted marker is not displayed.
The settings have now been checked several times. Unfortunately, I can not find the mistake.
The MapsActivity was implemented with the statement  `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);` in a MapsFragment.

Before I am implemented I give Android Studio the Latitude Data directly from the MapsFragment. This works.

Hope anyone can help me.

MapsActivity:

```
package in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map123);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }

}
```

activity_maps:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map123"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <application
        android:name=".LapitChat"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Do What?"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDXdb5I_QzviEl7CMIMn71auYgbcnuS_3o" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".StatusActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UsersActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

ActivityMain:

```
package in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private MapsActivity mapsActivity;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Do What?");

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


            mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        }


        //Tabs
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabPager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }










    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null){

            sendToStart();

        } else {

            mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");

        }

    }





    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser != null) {

            mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

        }

    }

    private void sendToStart() {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);


        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_logout_btn){

            mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendToStart();

        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_settings_btn){

            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);

        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.main_all_btn){

            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UsersActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `onMapReady` gets invoked ?

Comment: please put the another latitude and longitude coordinates 
try this line .
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(33.8688, 151.2093);

Comment: It does not work with other coordinates.
I made a console dump in OnMapReady but it's not called.
How and where should I call it exactly? I Think the complety MapsActivity is not load, only the activity_maps was load.

Comment: i think you need to add SHA1 key and package name in https://console.cloud.google.com for your project

Comment: I think everything is alright with the API. He shows me Traffiq when I open the app.
I think it's because the MapsActivity is not called

Comment: The Problem is, that the MapsActivity its not called. I implemented the Fragment in a TabLayout with  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                MapsFragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
                return mapsFragment;                                                     How can i implement the start from my MapsActivity in this?